# What purpose does empty exception class serve?

Tags: php, class, exception

I have seen implementation for exceptions like:

```
<?php

class TestE extends Exception {}

class MyTest {

    public function __construct() {
        try{
            throw new TestE('This is an exception!');
        }catch(Exception $exc){
            var_dump($exc);
        }

        echo '2';
    }
}

$o = new MyTest();
```

where a custom exception class like `TestE` is defined but kept empty as above. What purpose does it achieve? I could have easily used:

```
throw new Exception('This is an exception')
```

instead of

```
throw new TestE('This is an exception')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending the [`Exception`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php) class is useful because it allows a finer control on the exception handling.

The class you posted can be used like this:

```
try {
    // Some code that can throw Exception, InvalidArgumentException or TestE
    // depending on the specific issue it encountered

} catch (TestE $e) {
    // TestE is thrown when a specific issue happens; it requires particular handling
    // f.e. it can be logged and ignored because the program can continue 
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    // This exception usually signals a coding error;
    // for example, an invalid type of an argument passed to a function
    // It needs a different handling than TestE; f.e. it can be logged
    // and a notification email sent to the developer
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // This is the most generic exception type
    // It catches all the exceptions that were not caught by the other branches
    // A specific handling is not possible for them; log them and exit the program
}
```

On the other hand, the class `Exception` contains all the members and methods you need to use them. Usually there is no need to add more members and method.

This is why the `Exception` class is extended but the children classes do not provide any new functionality (most of the times).

Answer (score 1):

The name of the exception gets logged in to the log file / rsyslog etc. Also your framework could have exception handlers that handles particular kinds of exception by checking the class name of the exception being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

It's a more concrete error than common `Exception`.

You can catch only that exception or the whole branch of it.

```
class PostException extends Exception {}
class LimitExceededOnPostException extends PostException {}

// When you need to catch any post-related exception...

try {

} catch (PostException $e) {

}

// When you need to catch exactly the `LimitExceededOnPostException`...

try {

} catch (LimitExceededOnPostException $e) {
    // do some related things
}
```

Also take a look at a difference between `LogicException` and `RuntimeException`. Generally you shouldn't extend `Exception`, extend one of those two.